# How to use git to send cloned repository to a different one via VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

New to VS Code and Git.  I was able to get code setup with git on my windows 10 machine.  I can clone the repository I want to a new local folder on my desktop and view the code.

I also created a new private repository on GitHub (as a destination point) and want to first send the code (no changes made) to this new destination and can't seem to find a way/method to do this with VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

```
git init

git add . 

git commit -m "First commit"

git remote add origin https://git....

git push -u origin master
```

Comment: That's the Git command-line way; OP seems to want to know some sort of entirely-in-VScode way.

Answer (score 0):

1. use this `git remote -v` to verify remote repository
2. use `git remove nameOfReporistory` to remove the existing repository
3. `git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git`  to add your repository

for more information : [enter link description here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories)